# Asymptotic behaviour of solution of a nonlinear ODE near infinity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, laurent-series

Consider the nonlinear ODE
\begin{align}
y':=\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{y}}
\end{align}
where $y$ is (as usual) a function of $x$. I am interested to obtain a Laurent series solution $y$ of this ODE when $x$ is big. My guess is that since $y'>0$, $y$ should be increasing, and so when $x$ is big, $y$ is big, but then $y'$ would be close to $1$, which makes $y$ almost like a linear function when $x$ is big. Thus I expect
\begin{align}
y=x+a_0+\frac{a_1}{x}+\frac{a_2}{x^2}+\cdots,\qquad x>>1
\end{align}
but then I am not sure if this is correct and I would be glad to know any techniques to obtain such Laurent series solution.

Any comment, hint and answer are greatly appreciated. In particular, if there is any reference for problems alike, I would also be glad to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The d.e. is separable, and its general solution can be written as
$$ x + c = \sqrt{y^2-y} + \frac{1}{2} \ln \left(-1 + 2 y + 2 \sqrt{y^2-y}\right)$$
As $y \to +\infty$ the right side is $y + \frac{1}{2} \ln(y) + O(1)$.
Thus we should have $y \sim x - \frac{1}{2} \ln(x) + O(1)$.
In particular, it is **not** a Laurent series because of the logarithmic term: the 
solution has a branch point, not a pole, at $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. One small question: I'm not familiar with the theory of Riemann surface, and so would be grateful if you can explain (briefly will do) what is a branch point at infinity.

Comment: It's just like a branch point in $\mathbb C$.  There is no $R$ such that the function is analytic in $\{z: |z| > R\}$.  If you go around a circle $|z|=R$, when you come back to the start the value will be different from what it started as.

Answer (score 2):

We could solve this differential equation exactly using separation of variables.

$$\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{y}}} = x + C$$

Substitute $ y = \cosh^2 t$

$$ \implies \int \frac{2\cosh t \sinh t}{\sqrt{\tanh^2 t}} dt = \int 2 \cosh^2 t dt = \int 1 + \cosh 2t dt$$

$$ \implies \cosh^{-1}(y) + y\sqrt{y^2-1} = x + C$$

In other words, for large $x$ we get

$$ x \approx y^2 + \log(y) \implies y \approx \sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{W}(2e^{2x})}{2}} \approx \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{\frac{\log x}{2}}$$

from Lambert-W's known expansion for large x, but it would end up having $\log\log x$ terms and so on.

Comment: I have the feeling that you lost a factor $2$ somewhere. Good answer and $\to +1$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the $\log y$ was really a $\log 2y$ but for large values, $\log 2y \approx \log y$. Edit: I see what you mean and I have fixed the post. Thank you!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I actually back substituted incorrectly, your answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Almost repeating what Robert Israel answered, the general solution is
$$x+c=\sqrt{(y-1) y}+\sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{y-1}\right)$$
Expanded as a series for large values of $y$
$$x+c=\left(\log(2)-\frac 12\right)+y+\frac{1}{2}\log (y)-\frac{3}{8 y}+O\left(\frac{1}{y^2}\right)$$
So, for large values of $y$, solving
$$x+d=y+\frac 12 \log(y)\implies y=\frac{1}{2} W\left(2 e^{2 (x+d)}\right)$$ where appears Lambert function (as already introduced in Ninad Munshi's answer).

For large values, using the first term of the expansion of Lambert function, this is $$y\sim \frac 12 \left(\log (t)-\log (\log (t))\right)\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=2 e^{2 (x+d)}$$